# What do we call the end of school everyday

Tags: word-choice, word-request

What's the appropriate term to describe the end of classes in school at the end of the day everyday (to resume again the very next day). Can we call it school break or disassembly or is there a specific term to describe it?

Comment: School is **out** for the day.

Comment: Welcome to ELL!  Great question.  I love the creative thought of using “disassembly”. Answer added! Keep contributing!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The **end of the day**,
- The **end of the school day**,

or maybe (in spoken American English)

- “the end of **last period** today.”

are all fine.

- **Dismissal**, or
- **Dismissal today**

would be the formal term in American usage.

*School break* refers to the holidays between terms, like *winter break, winter vacation*, *spring break* or *summer break*.

## “Assembly” and “Disassembly”

A quick note: “Assembly” doesn’t mean the start of the school day, it means a formal (or mandatory) gathering, like this:

> [image: formal gathering]
>   - user Mailer_Diablo at [wikimedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Students_of_Nan_Hua_High_School,_Singapore,_in_the_school_hall_-_20060127.jpg)

*Disassembly* refers to *taking apart machines*, not groups of people.  This is even though “assembly” can mean a group of people **assembled** together, especially at a school.

Answer (score 3):

[**home time**](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/home_time)
*[mass noun]*
The time at which school or work finishes and one goes home.
*‘The bell rang for home time’*

It's true that definition includes ***...or work*** [finishes], but I at least think it's essentially a *childish* usage. In the "grown-up" world of work, we use a different (slightly "slangy") alternative to avoid that association...

[**knocking-off time**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/knocking-off-time)
*[noun, informal]*
The time when you finish work.
*'Come on, then. It's knocking-off time'.*

(Note that the above are both primarily *British* English usages.)

Comment: Important to add these are British English, and not found in American usage.

Comment: @whiskeychief: Good point. I'd expect the average American to understand these usages (just as we Brits know Americans use ***hood / trunk*** for a car ***bonnet / boot***), but they wouldn't be so likely to ***use*** my suggestions above. Answer text amended to reflect this, and thanks!

Comment: No problem!  Knocking off: yes, but “Home time”: so that means 3pm or 5pm (the hour at which I’m allowed to go home), not “5 pm to 8 am (the time I spend at home)?    We really can learn something new every day!

Comment: Yeah - both *home time* and *knocking-off time* specifically refer to the time school/work *finishes*, not the time when you actually get back home. There might be relatively unusual contexts where someone would use *home time* to mean *time spent at home* (an extended period, not a point in time), but to me that would be at least a *slightly* "quirky, self-conscious" usage (akin to ***me time*** - time devoted to one's *own* satisfaction, not the needs of other people or external circumstances).